# How to the get FCM token for inactive users? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

I have the FCM token, and token refreshed when user is using the application.
I want to send push notifications to users who have not logged into the app recently.

As the FCM token expires, how do I implement Firebase Messaging, and get the user FCM token when the app is not opened for days?

Comment: You can save last refresh and use it to query  for inactive users

Answer (score 0):

The token doesn't expire, it may change in the following cases.

1. The app is restored on a new device
2. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
3. The user clears app data.

To handle these cases the application should retrieve the current token at initial startup and send it to the server.

See [Best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) for more information.